# Is onenote skydrive connection encrypted?

Tags: security, encryption, microsoft-onenote

I want to know wheather onenote's network packet are encrypted or not. For example if i stored password in one of onenote's book, could it be easily captured while synchronisation?

Comment: I've added a new answer; while technically yours is correct, its not the entire story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was given me in technet forums:
OneNote is stored the content in SkyDrive. All network flow transmission of Skydrive data occurs over an encrypted channel (SSL).

Comment: Yes, I can see that "over the wire" the data is encrypted; however the answer about the data being store in plain text, once arrived at its resting place has not been answered. I believe it is not encrypted by default and that one must take this additional, manual step and encrypt any note or notebook.

The only alternative that I know of, that encrypts by default is Turtl (https://turtlapp.com/), although in early stages of development, it can be hosted on site and will offer a SaaS version soon.

Answer (score 3):

While transferring of the notebook to OneNote is encrypted, the actual notebook itself is not unless you password protect it.  What that means is that someone at the data center could read your notebooks.  This could happen for example as the result of a court order.  So if you want to store passwords in a notebook, make sure to password protect it.